# Como alterar a cor do INPUT quando ultrapassar determinado número de caracteres?

Tags: css, html5

Tenho este `CSS` do `INPUT`, e gostaria que o mesmo alterasse a cor do background quando ultrapassasse 70 caracteres.

**CSS**

```
.imv-frm-campo{
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #D9ECF1;
    border: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="nome_cliente" type="text" class="imv-frm-campo">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só com CSS você não consegue. Crie um evento `oninput` em JavaScript para detectar interação no `input` e disparar uma função.

Pode especificar pelo `name`: `document.querySelector("[name='nome_cliente']")`

Verifique se mais de 70 caracteres foram digitados com `this.value.length >= 70` com um operador ternário alternando a cor do fundo se o `value` for maior ou menor que o número de caracteres.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei para 3 caracteres apenas para ilustrar:

```js
document.querySelector("[name='nome_cliente']").oninput = function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = this.value.length >= 3 ? "red" : "#D9ECF1";
}
```

```css
.imv-frm-campo{
    width: 95%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #D9ECF1;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input name="nome_cliente" type="text" class="imv-frm-campo">
```

Se quiser um código genérico para vários campos com limites diferentes: https://jsfiddle.net/kLg8q7dr/

Comment: Tem como eu especificar qual INPUT quero aplicar? Tipo pelo name do input.

Comment: Coloquei da seguinte forma `<script type="text/javascript">
      document.querySelector("input").oninput = function(){
   this.style.backgroundColor = this.value.length >= 3 ? "red" : "#D9ECF1";
}
    </script>` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Para mim desde o primeiro exemplo não funcionou

Comment: Coloque o código entre: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ código aqui });`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Porque para mim só funcionou com a inclusão deste código?

Comment: O `DOMContentLoaded` só é executado após os elementos terem sidos acrregados na página.

Comment: Se quiser um código genérico para vários campos: https://jsfiddle.net/kLg8q7dr/